# ¿Cómo listar archivos y luego recorrer su contenido con node js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[Proyecto completa en repl.it](https://repl.it/@MiguelTenorio/leerLinea)

Tengo textos planos en una carpeta compartida *Z:\archivos-txt* y tiene siguientes características.

```
FA-F008-00008245
FA-F008-00008246
FA-F008-00008247
FA-F007-00011908
FA-F007-00011909
```

dentro de cada archivo tiene la siguiente información que varia de acuerdo a cada factura:

```
UNB+AUTOMATIZACIONCEN+20600760300+20167925509+INVOIC+0+00009189
UNB+PROCESAMIENTO+2.0+1.0++01+F007-00011909+2018-12-27+USD+20167921000+6+-+NOMBRE EMPRESA+150115+DIRECION NRO. 145 INT. 204++LIMA+LIMA+LIMA+PE+20600760361+6+NOMBRE SOCIO COMERCIAL+DIRECCION SOCIO COMERCIAL+694.69+125.05+819.74+103.80+0.00+819.74+F109FA+CORREO@hotmail.com+0+++030590+CONDICION DE PAGO+2018-12-27+0320050001338+++2005+103.80+10+++
NOT,0002,7198002-7198003-3331410
NOT,0003,www.PAGINA.com   CORREO: CORREO@CORREO.com
NOT,0014,01.- Almacen Principal 
NOT,0015,NOMBRE VENDEDOR
NOT,0030,AGENCIA NOMBRE
NOT,0101,13.00%
NOT,0102,13.00%
NOT,0103,13.00%
NOT,0104,13.00%
NOT,0105,13.00%
```

intente recorrer cada archivo y guardar en un array, cuando le pongo *console.log(global.arrayFac)* imprime el array pero con json suplicados

```js
 rl.on('close', function () {
   // res.render('rutas/home', {txt: global.arrayFac})
   console.log(global.arrayFac)

  })
```

y cuando pongo así, me bota error en la consola

```js
 rl.on('close', function () {
   res.render('rutas/home', {txt: global.arrayFac})
   //console.log(global.arrayFac)

  })
```

quiero imprimir en un tabla con el las dos primeras lineas del txt pero no puedo haciendo de la siguiente forma **res.render('rutas/home', {txt: global.arrayFac})** y luego recorrer con **express-handlebars**

[Proyecto completa en repl.it](https://repl.it/@MiguelTenorio/leerLinea)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const path = require('path');

var _ruta = './archivosTxt'
var jo={};
global.arrayFac = [];
var jsonFac = {}

 fs.readdir(_ruta, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    files.filter(function(files) {
        return fs.statSync(_ruta+'/'+files).isFile()
    }).forEach(function(files) {
        // console.log(files)
        var ext = path.extname(_ruta+'/'+files);
        // console.log(ext)
        var nombreCompleto = path.basename(_ruta+'/'+files);
        var nombre_simple = nombreCompleto.replace(ext, "");
        // console.log("---> %s : %s (%s)", nombreCompleto, nombre_simple, ext);
        // ---> FA-F008-00008797.txt : FA-F008-00008797 (.txt)


        // ----------
        var rl = readline.createInterface({
          input: fs.createReadStream(_ruta+'/'+files)
        })
        rl.on('line', (line)=>{
          facturasTxt(line)
        });
        rl.on('close', function () {
          // res.render('rutas/home', {txt: global.arrayFac})
          console.log(global.arrayFac)
          // leerCarpeta()
        })
    });
});

  function facturasTxt(txtData) {
        var arrayDeCadenasURB = txtData.split('+')
        // var arrayDeCadenasURB = splitMas;
        if(`${arrayDeCadenasURB[0]}.${arrayDeCadenasURB[1]}`==='UNB.PROCESAMIENTO'){
            jsonFac['RucEmisor'] = Number(arrayDeCadenasURB[9]);
            jsonFac['Documento'] = separaSerieYnumero(arrayDeCadenasURB[6]);
            jsonFac['Fecha'] = new Date(arrayDeCadenasURB[7]);
            jsonFac['Moneda'] =arrayDeCadenasURB[8];
            jsonFac['TipoDocumento'] = Number(arrayDeCadenasURB[5]);
            jsonFac['vendedor'] = '';

            jsonFac['RucCliente'] = Number(arrayDeCadenasURB[20]);
            jsonFac['Nombreliente'] = arrayDeCadenasURB[22];
            jsonFac['DireccionCliente'] = arrayDeCadenasURB[23];
            jsonFac['OpGrabada'] = arrayDeCadenasURB[24];
            jsonFac['IGV'] = arrayDeCadenasURB[25];
            jsonFac['ImporteTotal'] = arrayDeCadenasURB[29];

            global.arrayFac.push(jsonFac)
        } else {
          //  console.log('PENDEJO, ALGO SALIO MAL');

        }

    }

    function separaSerieYnumero(serie_numero){
        var data = serie_numero.split('-')
        var serieNumero = {
          serie: data[0],
          numero:Number(data[1])
        }
        return serieNumero;
    }
```